# Invoking method with name pattern

Tags: java, syntax

I need to call some functions generated by some libs. I will need to call `fucntion1`, `function2`, ..., `function10` one by one. Instead of writing them all out on the code, is there any clever way to code it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *could* use [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

```
Some some = new Some();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    some.getClass().getMethod("function" + i).invoke(some);
}
```

Comment: Would it be interpreted at Runtime?

Comment: Truly, it will. See also the link to the reflection tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Expression class from java.beans package

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/beans/package-summary.html

construct a expression object.

```
Expression(Object target,String methodName,Object[] arguments)
```

and then on the expression object you can use getValue()

Cheers!